# Function Declaration using specific datatypes

Tags: python-3.x, function, spyder, function-declaration

`def StrongestNeighbour(neighbours: list[int])-> list[int]:`

this kind of function declaration is only working in my vs code but not in spyder what is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably with Spyder you are running Python version <3.9+ and with VSCode is Python >=3.9+

The thing is that before Python 3.9, for type hints like the one you show, the syntax is a little bit different:

```
from typing import List

def strongestNeighbour(neighbours: List[int]) -> List[int]:
    return neighbours

strongestNeighbour([1,2,3,4])
```

Note the import from the `typing` module and the uppercase `L`.

You can check the Python 3.8 typing docs for more information on the import and the overall syntax: https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/typing.html

However, if you use Python 3.9 then you can use the `list[int]` syntax as you have it. You can check the Python 3.9 typing docs for more information: https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/typing.html